# Label TiledMap Libgdx Java

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a question for you:

in my tiled map I added a rectangle object.

My question is:

How Do I add a text label in this rectangle by code?

In particular:

when I render tiled map for every rectangle object in the map I want to add in this rectangle a text label

Now I tried this:

```
 for(MapObject obj: tiledMap.getLayers().get("object").getObjects()){

                if(obj instanceof RectangleMapObject){

                    //I don't know what do

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text as a property to your rectangle in tmx editor (just click on rectangle twice if you use Tiled), like this:

```
has_text (key) - any text (value)
```

Than check if  `RectangleMapObject` has the "has_text" key property, like this:

```
MapProperties properties = object.getProperties();
if (properties.containsKey("has_text")) {
    String textToSet= (String) properties.get("has_text");
    float x = (Float) properties.get("x");
    float y = (Float) properties.get("y");
    //Now create you can create the label, you have text(seted in tmx editor) 
    //and x,y are coordinates of the rectangle.
}
```